# scala string.split does not work

Tags: string, scala, split

Following is my REPL output. I am not sure why string.split does not work here.

```
val s = "Pedro|groceries|apple|1.42"
s: java.lang.String = Pedro|groceries|apple|1.42

scala> s.split("|")
res27: Array[java.lang.String] = Array("", P, e, d, r, o, |, g, r, o, c, e, r, i, e, s, |, a, p, p, l, e, |, 1, ., 4, 2)
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you use quotes, you're asking for a regular expression split.  `|` is the "or" character, so your regex matches nothing or nothing.  So everything is split.

If you use `split('|')` or `split("""\|""")` you should get what you want.

Comment: good one. In scala, what is the difference between '' and ""?

Comment: `"""stuff"""` quotes a literal string.  `"stuff"` interprets escape characters.  Since backslash is an escape character _both_ in Java strings _and_ regexes, you would need to escape the escape character to get it into the regex: `"\\|"`.  This gets confusing _very_ quickly, so it's better to use triple quotes and go for a literal string.

Comment: and... is 'somestring' same as """somestring"""?

Comment: `'c'` is a single character.  `"""This is a (literal) string, not a single character."""`

Comment: Ah...I got it. I am from JavaScript, and it look like I have forgotten few basic things.

Answer (score 8):

`|` is a special *regular expression* character which is used as a logical operator for *`OR`* operations.

Since [java.lang.String#split(String regex);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes in a regular expression, you're splitting the string with *"none OR none"*, which is a whole another speciality about regular expression splitting, where *none* essentially means *"between every single character"*.

To get what you want, you need to escape your regex pattern properly. To escape the pattern, you need to prepend the character with `\` and since `\` is a special `String` character (think `\t` and `\r` for example), you need to actually double escape so that you'll end up with `s.split("\\|")`.

For full Java regular expression syntax, see [java.util.regex.Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 6):

Split takes a regex as first argument, so your call is interpreted as "empty string or empty string". To get the expected behavior you need to escape the pipe character "\\|".