# groupBykey in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

New to spark here and I'm trying to read a pipe delimited file in spark. My file looks like this:

```
user1|acct01|A|Fairfax|VA
user1|acct02|B|Gettysburg|PA
user1|acct03|C|York|PA
user2|acct21|A|Reston|VA
user2|acct42|C|Fairfax|VA
user3|acct66|A|Reston|VA
```

and I do the following in scala:

```
scala> case class Accounts (usr: String, acct: String, prodCd: String, city: String, state: String)
defined class Accounts

scala> val accts = sc.textFile("accts.csv").map(_.split("|")).map(
     | a => (a(0), Accounts(a(0), a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4)))
     | )
```

I then try to group the key value pair by the key, and this is not sure if I'm doing this right...is this how I do it?

```
scala> accts.groupByKey(2)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[Accounts])] = ShuffledRDD[4] at groupByKey at <console>:26
```

I thought the (2) is to give me the first two results back but I don't seem to get anything back at the console...

If I run a distinct...I get this too..

```
scala> accts.distinct(1).collect(1)
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: PartialFunction[(String, Accounts),?]
              accts.distinct(1).collect(1)
```

EDIT:
Essentially I'm trying to get to a key value pair nested mapping. For example, user1 would looke like this:

```
user1 | {'acct01': {prdCd: 'A', city: 'Fairfax', state: 'VA'}, 'acct02': {prdCd: 'B', city: 'Gettysburg', state: 'PA'}, 'acct03': {prdCd: 'C', city: 'York', state: 'PA'}}
```

trying to learn this step by step so thought I'd break it down into chunks to understand...

Comment: To limit the number of result, you would want to use `take(int)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have better luck if you put your data into a DataFrame if you've already gone through the process of defining a schema. First off, you need to modify the split comment to use single quotes. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284771/scala-string-split-does-not-work)). Also, you can get rid of the `a(0)` in the beginning. Then, converting to a DataFrame is trivial. (Note that DataFrames are available on spark 1.3+.)

```
val accts = sc.textFile("/tmp/accts.csv").map(_.split('|')).map(a => Accounts(a(0), a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4)))
val df = accts.toDF()
```

Now `df.show` produces:

```
+-----+------+------+----------+-----+
|  usr|  acct|prodCd|      city|state|
+-----+------+------+----------+-----+
|user1|acct01|     A|   Fairfax|   VA|
|user1|acct02|     B|Gettysburg|   PA|
|user1|acct03|     C|      York|   PA|
|user2|acct21|     A|    Reston|   VA|
|user2|acct42|     C|   Fairfax|   VA|
|user3|acct66|     A|    Reston|   VA|
+-----+------+------+----------+-----+
```

It should be easier for you to work with the data. For example, to get a list of the unique users:

```
df.select("usr").distinct.collect()
```

produces

```
res42: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([user1], [user2], [user3])
```

For more details, check out the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).

Comment: so I went through those docs but how do I get groupBy to work? I've tried df.groupBy("usr").collect(), df.select(),groupby().collect, and various other ways but can't get it to work...

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? I think there's maybe some confusion over what the `groupBy` operator does. You need to apply some kind of aggregation so that Spark knows how to aggregate all of the records corresponding to a given key. For instance, `df.groupBy("usr").count().collect()` will give you the number of records corresponding to each distinct user. You can look at the [API docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData) to see what kinds of functions you can use to aggregate records.

Comment: just made an edit to show the end goal...essentially trying to take the csv file and convert it to a key value pair mapping...

Answer (score 0):

3 observations that may help you understand the problem:

1)
`groupByKey(2)` does not return first 2 results, the parameter 2 is used as number of partitions for the resulting RDD. See [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).

2) `collect` does not take `Int` parameter. See [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

3) `split` takes 2 types of parameters, `Char` or `String`. String version uses Regex so `"|"` needs escaping if intended as literal.

Comment: I'm think I'm still confused by this...I see groupByKey(K, V) and groupByKey(Partition). How do I just simply pull the results back into a list. I think I have to use groupByKey, right? But do I use partition or K, V?