# What the difference between using single quote and double quote in split() method in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera

I am working on the cca-175 practice questions. I am given a text file which is split by `|`:

```
Christopher|Jan 11, 2015, |5 
Kapil|11 Jan, 2015|5
Thomas|6/17/2014|5
John|22-08-2013|5
Mithun|2013|5
Jitendra||5
```

Then I saved the file as an RDD and tried to map it. However, when used single quote and double quote in the `split` method, Scala returns two different outcomes and using the single quote is right.

Using single quote`line.split('|')` , it returned: 
`Array[String] = Array(Christopher, Jan 11, 2015, 5)`, which is right.

Using double quote  `line.split("|")`, it returned : 
`Array[String] = Array(C, h, r, i, s, t, o, p, h, e, r, |, J, a, n, " ", 1, 1, , " ", 2, 0, 1, 5, |, 5)`, 
which is not what I need.

Can anyone help me with the question?
Thanks!

```
scala> val feedbackmap = feedback.map(line=>line.split('|'))
feedbackmap: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:29

scala> feedbackmap.first
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: first at <console>:32
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 4 (first at <console>:32) with 1 output partitions
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 4 (first at <console>:32)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:29), which has no missing parents
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.4 KB, free 510.7 MB)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2003.0 B, free 510.7 MB)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on localhost:43371 (size: 2003.0 B, free: 511.1 MB)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1008
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at <console>:29)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 4.0 with 1 tasks
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5, localhost, partition 0,ANY, 2171 bytes)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/junyanxu/scenario_37/feedback.txt:0+58
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5). 2173 bytes result sent to driver
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5) in 7 ms on localhost (1/1)
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 4 (first at <console>:32) finished in 0.007 s
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 finished: first at <console>:32, took 0.012483 s
19/04/10 14:15:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
res3: Array[String] = Array(Christopher, Jan 11, 2015, 5)
scala> 19/04/10 14:20:55 WARN SparkContext: Killing executors is only supported in coarse-grained mode
19/04/10 14:20:55 WARN ExecutorAllocationManager: Unable to reach the cluster manager to kill executor driver!
val
scala> val feedbackmap2 = feedback.map(line=>line.split("|"))
feedbackmap2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:29
scala> feedbackmap2.first
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: first at <console>:32
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 5 (first at <console>:32) with 1 output partitions
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 5 (first at <console>:32)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 5 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:29), which has no missing parents
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.4 KB, free 510.7 MB)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2003.0 B, free 510.7 MB)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on localhost:43371 (size: 2003.0 B, free: 511.1 MB)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 6 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1008
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 5 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:29)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 5.0 with 1 tasks
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6, localhost, partition 0,ANY, 2171 bytes)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/user/junyanxu/scenario_37/feedback.txt:0+58
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6). 2244 bytes result sent to driver
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6) in 12 ms on localhost (1/1)
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 5 (first at <console>:32) finished in 0.012 s
19/04/10 14:22:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 5 finished: first at <console>:32, took 0.040166 s
res4: Array[String] = Array(C, h, r, i, s, t, o, p, h, e, r, |, J, a, n, " ", 1, 1, ,, " ", 2, 0, 1, 5, |, 5)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524642/splitting-string-with-pipe-character

Answer (score 2):

in scala single quote denotes a char so split('|') uses the | char. When you use double quotes you use a string and specifically split can accept a regex string so the unescaped | inside a string is interpreted as the regex or

Answer (score 1):

I think Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz made a good point about the meaning of the `|` inside a string as argument to split: it's a [logical operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical).

Moreover, what's happening here is that you use regex which means *empty string or empty string*. As empty string can be found basically anywhere in a `String` (if it helps you you can understand that `"ab"` is equivalent to `"a" + "" + "b"`), split is made between each character.

See also [scala string.split does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284771/scala-string-split-does-not-work) which states:

> If you use `split('|')` or `split("""\|""")` you should get what you want.

Indeed, an escaped `|` isn't anymore considered as a logical operator but as the character itself in a regex expression.